# Is there an easy way to add custom error messages in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Suppose we have a grammar where there is an element that was expected but is not found. Assume that the backtracking is disabled, i.e. the element is preceded by a `-` sign.

Is there any way in the library to set a custom error message, such as "Foo was needed", on that element? Or is the only way to catch the parse exception and work it out using the location information?

Say:

```
from pyparsing import *

grammar = (
    Literal("//")
    - Word(alphanums)("name")
    + Suppress(White()[1,...])
    + Word(alphanums)("operation")
).leave_whitespace()

grammar.run_tests("""
//name op
// opnoname
""", print_results=True)
```

The output for the 2nd line is:

```
// opnoname
  ^
ParseException: Expected W:(0-9A-Za-z), found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
FAIL: Expected W:(0-9A-Za-z), found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

I'd like a custom message, such as "name was needed" instead of the generic "Expected W:(0-9A0Za-z), found ' '".

So far it looks like catching the `ParseException`, modifying the `message` in it, and re-rasising it would be a solution. Am I missing something more fundamental?

---

For those curious: this came up when writing a [JCL (Job Control Language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language) parser.

I'm using latest pyparsing stable version at the moment: 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't custom error messages, but you can use `set_name` to give nice
names to the different elements of your grammar.

```py
identifier = Word(alphanums).set_name("identifier")
grammar = (
    Literal("//")
    - identifier("name")
    + White().suppress()
    + identifier("operation")
).leave_whitespace()
grammar.set_name("grammar")
```

Note the difference between `set_name` and `set_results_name`.
`set_name` gives a name to the expression itself, while
`set_results_name` (which you implicitly call when using the
`expr("name")` notation) is what assigns names to the parsed
results.

It is easier to see the distinction if you generate a
railroad diagram, and add `show_results_names=True`:

```py
grammar.create_diagram("grammar.html", show_results_names=True)
```

[image: grammar railroad diagram]

I've always wanted to let pyparsing deal with whitespace
when I can, and not explicitly show it in my grammar.
If you want to enforce no spaces between the leading '//'
and the `name` identifier, you can write like this:

```py
grammar = (
    Literal("//")
    - identifier("name").leave_whitespace()
    + identifier("operation")
)
```

Pyparsing's implicit whitespace skipping will take care
of the spaces between name and operation. `leave_whitespace`
on the `name` alone tells pyparsing not to skip whitespace
*before* parsing the `name` identifier. But you may have other
plans for further parts of this grammar, so I'll leave it
up to you which way to go on this.

I'm glad to see you are using `run_tests`! Here is a tip: you
can insert comments in your tests, and they will show up as
labels for each test in your output, like this:

```
grammar.run_tests("""\
# successful expression
//name op
# more than one space between name and operation - still works!
//name   op
# failing expression, missing second identifier
// opnoname
# failing expression, name but no operation
//namenoopn
# failing expression, space after '//'
// name op
""")
```

and get this output:

```
# successful expression
//name op
['//', 'name', 'op']
- name: 'name'
- operation: 'op'

# more than one space between name and operation - still works!
//name   op
['//', 'name', 'op']
- name: 'name'
- operation: 'op'

# failing expression, missing second identifier
// opnoname
// opnoname
  ^
ParseSyntaxException: Expected identifier, found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
FAIL: Expected identifier, found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)

# failing expression, name but no operation
//namenoopn
//namenoopn
           ^
ParseSyntaxException: Expected identifier, found end of text  (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
FAIL: Expected identifier, found end of text  (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)

# failing expression, space after '//'
// name op
// name op
  ^
ParseSyntaxException: Expected identifier, found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
FAIL: Expected identifier, found ' '  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

You can also insert blank spaces between tests for readability,
just like you would insert blank lines in your Python code.

Comment: Thank you so much for this in-depth reply. This is excellent and covers everything I need. Really, you went above and beyond. I’m very grateful.

Comment: Next on my list is finishing up a parser for COBOL. I may have one or two more questions. It takes a bit to get acquainted with the design patters/thrust in pyparsing’s API. They are good patterns, just not always obvious at first glance.

Comment: Please visit the wiki attached to the Github repo: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki There are pages with best practices and pitfalls to avoid.

Comment: *Pyparsing's implicit whitespace skipping will take care of the spaces between name and operation* That works great for freeform syntax. JCL is a mix of column-bound and freeform, and whitespace can't be arbitrarily long, it can't include line breaks, etc. I've had to remove some of the complexity for the question otherwise it'd be full of hair-rising details. Suffice it to say that line continuations are a first-class element in JCL syntax, and there's a couple variations of them. JCL parses great when coding the parser in assembly. Anything more versatile and it turns into a pain.

Comment: The above is not meant to detract from anything you said, just add some, eh, flavor on top. And what a flavor it is :)

Comment: Yes. I saw the page you linked, it makes for an interesting grammar (simple-looking, but some surprising complexity wrinkles!). You may be best by turning off whitespace skipping altogther - I think your use of `leave_whitespace` at the top-level (with `recursive=True`) will do. Or at the start, call `ParserElement.set_default_whitespace_chars("")`.